# Do discrete GPUs auto turn off while not in use?

Tags: power, gpu

I am planning to buy a desktop PC with a discrete GPU. I will use a 1080p monitor connected via HDMI. My workflow requires the PC to be kept on with the monitor turned off for more than 10 hrs daily. If GPU remains on when it is not being used, it might consume lots of power. So I want to know if GPUs auto turn of if display turns off or goes into sleep.

Comment: Second the duplicate mainly due to the answer which contained *Many modern cards usage very low power when idle for example my sapphire hd5770 consume 18w when idle and 108w when at its max.*.  That example card is already a few years old and things have gotten more energy efficient since that time.

Answer (score 0):

They don't turn off as such, but like CPUs they dynamically change their speed in accordance with the workload to minimize power usage. A GPU with no actual load applied doesn't use very much power compared to its maximum draw.

You can use a tool like GPU-Z to see the changing clock rate and look at the power draw.